# Can't scroll down on my website

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, scroll

So I've been working on this site http://developed-web.com/ and thought it'd look nice with this site plugin ([link](http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery))

The problem now is that I can't scroll down through my page. I've tried setting my page height to 1360px at every single place that I can think of but it won't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Setting the overflow to hidden tends to have that effect! Change it to `auto`, or just remove the overflow style as `auto` is default !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should change `overflow:hidden` to `overflow:scroll` in your `body` css properties

Answer (score 6):

`overflow` is `hidden` on your body, change it to `scroll`

```
body {
 height: 1360px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Better set it to auto, to avoid having a scrollbar if there is no overflow.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, the issue is `overflow:hidden`  on the body element. I'd recommend changing it to `overflow:auto` instead.

Looks like that particular style isn't in an external style sheet - I'd also have to recommend moving it (and the others in your `<head>` section) to your `style.css` file.

Additionally, I'd say lose your inline width and height declarations on `#wrapper`, `#mask`, and `.item`. They made my page stop oddly (I have a pretty large screen).